# Python 2.7 : retrieve netCDF4 file with ftplib

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, netcdf, ftplib, netcdf4

Here is my issue :
I download some netCDF4 files from an FTP server, in two different ways: via FileZilla and via a Python 2.7 script using ftplib.

Code of Python script (running on Windows) :

```
# download the file
try:
    ftp = FTP(server_address)
    ftp.login(server_login, server_pass)
    filepath = 'the_remote_rep/myNetCDF4File.nc'
    filename = 'myNetCDF4File.nc'
    local_dir = 'toto'
    new_file = open('%s/%s' % (local_dir, filename), "w")
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filepath, new_file.write)
    ftp.close()
    new_file.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error FTP : '" + str(e) + "'")

# update title into the file
try:
    fname = 'toto/myNetCDF4File.nc'
    dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(fname, mode='a')
    setattr(dataset, 'title', 'In Situ Observation Re-Analysis')
    dataset.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error netCDF4 : '" + str(e) + "'")
```

Then, I get this message :

> Error netCDF4 : '[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'toto/myNetCDF4File.nc''

When I try the second block of code with a netCDF4 file downloaded via FileZilla (the same file for example), there is no error. 
Also, when I try to get the netCDF version of the file using "ncdump -k", here is the response (OK with the other file) :

> ncdump: myNetCDF4File.nc: Invalid argument

In addition, files do not have the same size depending on the method :

- FileZilla : 22 972 Ko
- Python ftplib : 23 005 Ko

Is it a problem from ftplib when writing the retrieved file? Or did I miss some parameters to correctly encode the file?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : verbose messages from FileZilla :

```
...
Response:   230 Login successful.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 9
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 9
Status: Logged in
Trace:  Measured latency of 114 ms
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Reset(0) in state 14
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::FileTransfer()
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 0
Status: Starting download of /INSITU_OBSERVATIONS/myNetCDF4File.nc
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Reset(0) in state 0
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 1
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
Command:    PASV
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (193,68,190,45,179,16).
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 134.xx.xx.xx
Command:    RETR myNetCDF4File.nc
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for myNetCDF4File.nc (9411620 bytes).
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   226 Transfer complete.
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 7
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult(0) in state 7
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Reset(0) in state 7
Status: File transfer successful, transferred 9 411 620 bytes in 89 seconds
Status: Disconnected from server
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(66)
```

Comment: What line does throw the error? + Show us verbose FileZilla log file.

Comment: The line containing "dataset = netCDF4.Dataset(fname, mode='a')".

Comment: So when you replace `ftp.retrbinary` with `file.write` (e.g. by copying an existing local file) -- do you get the same error?

Comment: Please add also the debug log from ftplib, i.e. `ftp.set_debuglevel(2)`. Also, the file size given in the output from filezilla (9411620 bytes) does not match at all the file size you give in your question (22 972 Ko - whatever unit `Ko` is).

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this is a problem of binary configuration (thanks to your questions).

I added `ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')` before retrieving file with ftplib, then I modified writing parameter of local file as `new_file = open('%s/%s' % (local_ftp_path, filename), "wb")` to specify that's a binary file.

Now the file is readable after download via ftplib and has same size as downloaded from FileZilla.

Thanks to your contribution.

Comment: No need for `ftp.voidcmd('TYPE I')` -- `retrbinary` does that already.